# Definition of Phone Auth Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I created an app as a hobby using firebase and I found that it actually might be a nice app so I continued to work more seriously on it.

When I started checking the pricing of firebase I saw that in the authentication section it says:

[image]

I use in my app things such as `Auth.getUid()` and `auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )`

From what I understood, every time a user sign-up to my app by using the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` I will need to pay 0.06$.

On the other hand, in their site, there is an example of pricing and it says there:

[image]

Can someone please explain to me what is the definition of verification as it is mentioned in 0.06$/verification?

Couldn't find something understandable on their page.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Firebase Authentication services are free (*email-password, google, facebook etc*)
**EXCEPT** phone verification.

Here by "Phone verification", I mean creating user with their **mobile** and validating them by **OTP**.

You are **NOT** charged anything if you use *email-password* authentication.

The cost is only for **Phone-Auth** (*mobile-otp*).

I hope it is clear now :-)

Comment: Thats what I was trying to understand, if verification = OTP. Thank you

Comment: Although, keep a note: one **verification** means every OTP sent, **NOT** the user. A user who logs in two times would give you two verifications, not one!

Comment: This is an important question and I'm glad someone made it clear. It's really a shame google can't lower the cost to 0.01 or something like that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the free version, you can have upto 10k users signup and then it'll stop accepting for that month. If you use the blaze/spark plan (Whichever is the pais one), you'll pay for whatever you use like all the other services in that plan. So for starting you can operate on the free plan.

Comment: There is no limit and pricing for authentication providers other than Phone Auth. Moreover, the pricing in Phone Auth which says - **$0.06/verification**  is for every OTP sent (_not for each user_). If the same user login 2 times, the pricing would be of 2 verifications!

Comment: @s_o_m_m_y_e_e I would recommend you use the free plan as it is quite sustaining and enough but if you feel like you need a bigger plan and the firebase thing is too expensive for you, you can try setting up your own server which would authenticate the phones

Comment: I wrote facts which were quite unclear in your answer.